# How do I set the vertical axis to powers of 10?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

For my Google sheets chart I have set the vertical axis to a logarithmic scale. I would prefer this to be displayed as a powers of 10, is this possible?

**What I get:**

[image: Result]

**What I want:**

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a fairly extreme hack (that I accept most would not bother with) - the 'usual' overlay what you have with what you want, but a bit more tricky in Google Sheets than I am used to.

First plot the chart (as you have) then adjust the line spacing on a sheet behind the chart so that the rows match the labels for spacing. Chose a font colour for the vertical axis labels to blend into the background -on a (standard) white background select white.

Fill one column with `10`s and next to it another with digits for the required powers (largest number at the top). Adjust the vertical alignment of these columns (top for the powers and centre or bottom for the `10`s. Adjust the font sizes of each column to suit.

Copy the array into a drawing canvas, save it and move the result where required:

[image: WA111121 example]